# Change colour of jitter points according to facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I want to compare the number of different coloured flowers (red and green) at two different sites. I have a boxplot in ggplot2 with a jitter plot in the background. I want the colour of the jitter points to be different according to the colour of the flowers. Not sure how to do this! Is there a way to colour code my facets depending on the colour of the flower?

Some sample data:

```
site <- c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4))

colour <- c("red", "green", "red", "green", "red", "green", "red", "green")
number <- c(12, 24, 22, 14, 12, 16, 18, 17)

df <- data.frame(site, colour, number)
df$site <- as.factor(df$site)

ggplot(df, aes(site, number))+
  facet_wrap("colour")+
  geom_jitter(alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0, colour = "black")+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ggplot(df, aes(site, number))+
  facet_wrap(~colour)+
  geom_jitter(aes(col = colour), alpha = 0.3, show.legend = F) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0, colour = "black")+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "red"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Map color to your column name. If you want the color to be interpreted literally use an identity scale:

```
ggplot(df, aes(site, number))+
  facet_wrap(colour)+
  geom_jitter(aes(colour = colour), alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0, colour = "black") +
  scale_color_identity() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Answer (score 1):

While both answers here address your problem, I think they are unnecessarily convoluted.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(site, number)) +
  facet_wrap(~colour) +
  geom_jitter(alpha = 0.3, color = colour) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0, color = "black")
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2019-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

- You don't need `theme(legend.position = "none")` since within your `geoms` you don't have any arguments inside `aes()`.
- In one of the answers, while we set the legend position to `none` (it is needed there since `colour` is inside `aesthetics`)  we also have `show.legend = F` which is redundant.
- Your `colour` columns is already `c("red", "green")` so we don't need to use `scale_color`.